# I keep getting a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am trying to get the user to insert a string of at least 3 characters and if its even the program prints the first half, and if it is odd the program prints the middle 3. I keep receiving this error when I put in anything more than 3 characters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stringex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a string at least 3 characters long ");
String a = input.nextLine();


int numberofletters = a.length();

if (numberofletters < 3) {
    System.out.print("Sorry the string you entered is not long enough");
}
else if (numberofletters%2 == 0) {
    System.out.print(a.substring(0, numberofletters/2));
}
else {
    System.out.print(a.substring(numberofletters/2 - 1, numberofletters +2 ));
}


}
```

}

Comment: The last else statement is the one causing the problem. You might want to look at the "numberofletters +2" part.

Comment: Next time please add the full error description. Especially the line where it gets thrown would be helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment your issue is with this statement:

```
else {
    System.out.print(a.substring(numberofletters/2 - 1, numberofletters +2 ));
}
```

Looking at the documentation for [subString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) you can see the issue is with the endIndex you are passing in.  Since `numberofletters` refers to the length of your string, adding 2 to it will always index past the end of the string.

The documentation also helpfully shows what exceptions subString can throw and in what circumstance :

> Throws:
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, **or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object**, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

[Emphasis mine]